How do I format numbers with leading zeros efficiently in Python?
I have a set of floats in my script, and I'd like to print them from a method with a set number of leading zeros, and decimal points so that (for example):
0.0000 becomes 000.0000
12.1246 becomes 012.1245 etc.
I've tried using rjust and an f-string eg.
fX = str(str(x)).rjust(4,'0') # and
str(f'{x:0.4f}'

but can't seem to able to get the leading zeros. (I think it's the equivalent of using an Excel form 000.0000). Is there a straightforward way to do this in Python?

Try f'{x:08.4f}'. Where 0 mean 0-padding, 8 stand for the whole length of the padded output and 4 is the digits after the decimal point.

Thankyou Klaus D. I hadn't realized the the '8' actually represents the whole length, integral and mantissa, I think what's I didn't understand. But the f-string you provided gave exactly the result I was looking for!

You can generalise this with the following function:
def fmt(n: float, pre: int, post: int) -> str:
    return f"{n:0{pre+post+1}.{post}f}"

Where n is your floating point value, pre is the minimum number of digits preceding the decimal point and post is the minimum number of decimal places
print(fmt(12.1246, 3, 4))
print(fmt(0., 3, 4))

Output:
012.1246
000.0000


Thanks SIGHUP, that function makes the syntax clear.

This seem to work for me. See if it applies as it should for you.
def format_float(x):
    return f'{x:08.4f}'

# Example
numbers = [0.0000, 12.1246, 9.9, 123.456789]

for num in numbers:
    print(format_float(num))

The first 0 is to specify fill the missing numbers with 0 and 7 is the minimum length for the string
And the ouptut:
000.0000
012.1246
009.9000
123.4568

If you want to make sure every number after the point is also shown instead of cut to 4 you can just put a variable in place of 7
https://onecompiler.com/python/42t23yugh

This cannot possibly work due to syntax errors. Even if you fix the indentation and the quote terminator of the f-string, it will not produce the results you claim

My bad I got hard time editing code in this edditor. and def copied the wrong code lmfao
Gonna edit the response

Also instead of 7 it should have been 8 since the number of character also counts that point

Gotchya Minus, thanks
